# NullPointerException clojure.core/filter/fn

Tags: clojure

Why does:

```
(filter f xs)
```

, result in an error that starts like this:

> NullPointerException   clojure.core/filter/fn

Comment: It's not atypical for Clojure to leak its Java (or .NET) roots into user-visible error messages. You'll no doubt see more of these over time.

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying to make it easier for anyone (like me) who just puts error messages into Google when they can't work them out.

Comment: You'd probably want to look at the JVM bytecode that the Clojure code compiled into, then use a decompiler to see the Java source, then identify the cause of the NPE.

Comment: What is the function `f`?

Comment: The function f is nil.

Comment: @Ray Toal. Easiest way to identify the cause is to use a bit of trial and error. Go into the REPL and try `(filter nil [:a])` and `(filter identity nil)`. One of these will probably cause the same error message. I know the answer, just asked to get it on the record...

Comment: All good. Why not answer your own question? It's a very acceptable practice for adding to this site's knowledge base.

Comment: I think @Lukas already knows the (pretty simple) answer. I'll wait a bit for my suggested edit and if it doesn't come I'll answer myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `filter` does not accept nil as its first (function) argument.

IMO because when you look into `filter` implementation there is no check if `f` is a function or not. I expect that is done like this for a performance reason. E.g. `string` module doesn't check a given string for `nil` too, because of a performance (https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/string.clj#L19).

Comment: When spec is around will there be a check if `f` is not nil and a function (or something that can be used as a function (i.e. keyword))?? Then there might be better error messages at development time, but still this message in production.

Comment: What should the error message (ideally) say? If you can put that in your answer then the the question would be answered.